# Consistent time-keeping method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am fairly new to python and have been trying to make a program that prints a string one character at a time. I was originally using `time.sleep()` for the delay but it was very inconsistent and looked choppy. I now use `time.clock()` and compare it after the character is printed. It works better but is still choppy at times. Is there a very consistent method of timekeeping in python?

My code:

```
def typePrint(string, sec):
  from time import clock
  for char in string:
    strt = clock()
    print(char, end='', flush=True)
    while clock() - strt < sec:
      pass
  print()
```

Comment: What do you consider 'choppy'?

Comment: I'm concerned that the actual problem is time-slicing on your system.  If you're using the built-in timing methods (sleep / clock), your functional performance should be smooth.

Comment: @zwer , the time in between the letters being printed is inconsistent and varies by a noticeable amount.

Comment: That `while clock() - strt < sec: pass` is wasting a lot of CPU cycles. It's probably a Good Idea to avoid doing stuff like that. ;) [This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51390651/4014959) might give you some ideas about how to do fairly precise delays.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks that answer helped me. It works a lot better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another implementation using `time.sleep`:

```
def typePrint(string, sec):
    from time import sleep

    for char in string:
        print(char, end="", flush=True)
        sleep(sec)
    print()
```

Making a syscall (like `time.clock`) in a busy loop is a good way to get flaky behavior, especially on a loaded system.