# What are the ways to improve my metronome written in Python?

Tags: python, audio, metronome

I'm trying to write a python based metronome with librosa and sounddevice but I've came across some problems with it's accuracy. Here's the code:

```
from time import sleep, perf_counter
import librosa
import sounddevice as sd

    bpm = 200
    delay = 60/bpm
    tone = librosa.tone(440, sr=22050, length=1000)
    
    try:
        while True:
            sd.play(tone, 22050)
            sleep(delay)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

First of all, the upper limit for properly functioning metronome seems to be around 180bpm - if you set the bpm to be any higher then 200bpm then there is no sound produced. In slower tempos I can hear that metronme is not so consistent as it should be with spacing in between the clicks. I've runned [the script from this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389691/how-can-i-do-a-precise-metronome/51390651#51390651) and my results were pretty poor compared to the author of this answer(which was using "old single core 32 bit 2GHz machine" against my six-core 3.9GHz 64bit windows running):

```
150.0 bpm
+0.007575200
+0.006221200
-0.012907700
+0.001935400
+0.002982700
+0.006840000
-0.009625400
+0.003260200
+0.005553100
+0.000668100
-0.010895100
+0.017142500
-0.012933300
+0.001465200
+0.004203100
+0.004769100
-0.012183100
+0.002174500
+0.002301000
-0.001611100
```

So i wonder if my metronome problems are somehow correlated to these poor results and what I can do to fix it.
The second problem that I encounter is the way in which the metronome is switched off - I want it to be running up until the point where the user inputs a specific button, or in my case(no GUI) a specific value from the keyboard - let's say the space key. So as you can see now it works only with ctrl + c, but I have no idea how to implement interrupt with a specified key.

Comment: You should create a callback function and use the passed-in value `time.outputBufferDacTime` to calculate when exactly to write the "click" sound to the output buffer. This way the timing will be very accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code on a mac, the timing inconsistencies are noticeable but also the tempo was of quite a bit off from the set bpm.

This is mostly because `sleep()` isn't that accurate, but also because you have to account for the time that has elapsed since the last event. e.g. how much time did it take to call `sd.play()`

I don't know on what operating system you did run this, but most operating systems have a special timer for precise callbacks (e.g. Multimedia Timers on Windows). if you don't want a platform specific solution to improve the timing you could do a "busy wait" instead on `sleep()`. To do this you could sleep for have the delay, and then go into a loop where you constantly check the time elapsed.

```py
lastTime = perf_counter()
while True:
    currentTime = perf_counter()
    delta = abs(lastTime - currentTime)
    sleep(delay / 2.0)

    while True:
        currentTime = perf_counter()
        if (currentTime - lastTime >= delay):
            sd.play(tone, 22050)
            lastTime = currentTime
            break
```

Not a perfect solution but it'll get you closer.

You can further optimise the fraction of the delay that is spent sleeping to take load of the CPU.